# How can I use a custom assembly in SSRS that returns a list?

Tags: c#, vb.net, reporting-services

Is it possible to use a function from the custom assembly that return a list of Strings to populate a graph?

The functions takes several fields as inputs and returns a list with several strings like this one: "clientName+date+inputBandwidth+outputBandwidth"

I need to make a graph with two lines(in and out /put) over the dates in SSRS by iterating the resulting list.

But apparently i cannot do that, or can I?

If not, can i make a custom data Source that returns a data set with the fields I described above? If yes, can someone give an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried it yet? What does your code currently look like?

Comment: Load your custom assembly via SQL Server CLR capabilities.

Comment: I can use my assembly, but only one entry at a time. For example, getXXX(0), getXXX(1)... But i cannot fill a table like this... there are hundreds of items. If i do getXXX in a table SSRS says that it cannot work with object of list(of String).

Answer (score 0):

In the assembly i have this function:

public static string[] read_stream_vsat(string query, string repository_path)
    {
...

return strarray;
}

the strarray has lists of: (dateTime + ; + Input + ; Output)

But this part works well.

The problem is dealing with the List in the reporting service.

= filerw.read_stream_vsat("11;1234;3;" + s_date + ";" + e_date , "\\xx.xxx.xx.xx\repository")

Like that i get an error. but if i use

= filerw.read_stream_vsat("11;1234;3;" + s_date + ";" + e_date , "\\xx.xxx.xx.xx\repository")(0)
it works. But it just return one field, and i cannot fill a graph by passing it one entry at a time.

I'm sorry i didn't put code before, but this is not a code problem.

I just couldn't find any information if it is possible to fill a graph using values that are retrieved from the assembly in a array of strings(same probably with List of Strings).

I cannot do a query directly to the database since i need to iterate files to fill the string array.